# "SET"ing variable from other variable is not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I may be missing something or forgotten something but when I attempt to "SET" a variable within a batch file the value of another variable from a FOR loop, it does not work.

```
ECHO OFF
set /p inputfile="Enter the server list name: "
for /f %%z in (%inputfile%) do (
for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2,3 delims=," %%a in (%%z.csv) do (
    set inst=%%b
    @echo Service Name: %%a
    @echo %inst%
    @echo Description: %%b
    @echo Install Path: %%c
)
)
pause
```

My end goal is to replace the "\" present within the install path retrieved with "/" so that it will be compatible with a separate java app. During testing the variable "inst" comes back empty.

The syntax I am hoping to use is here: http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

`SET` command works. What you need is [Enable Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)

> Delayed Expansion will cause variables to be expanded at execution
>   time rather than at parse time, this option is turned on with the
>   `SETLOCAL` command. When delayed expansion is in effect variables may be
>   referenced using `!variable_name!` (in addition to the normal
>   `%variable_name%`)

```
ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion
set /p "inputfile=Enter the server list name: "
for /f %%z in (%inputfile%) do (
  for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2* delims=," %%a in (%%z.csv) do (
    set "inst=%%b"
    @echo Service Name: %%a
    @echo !inst! "!inst:\=/!"
    @echo Description: %%b
    @echo Install Path: %%c
)
)
pause
```

Answer (score 1):

Brackets make multiple lines 1 line. Therefore you just need to move the echo's outside of the brackets so they are on a new line.

Variables are expanded when line is read. Therefore changes won't be noticed till the next line.

For multi command lines you can force expansion at execution time using `!Var!` syntax and turning this on with `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion`.

This is syntax to use to replace stuff `set  file=%windir:\=\\%` replaces `\` with `\\` in `%windir%`